# Invalide parameter number in PDO statement

Tags: pdo

I am having trouble with the below PDO code, which is throwing this error:

Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number'

I know that the $theID variable is working just fine, grabbing the variable and storing it as I have used it elsewhere on the page. The problem lies somewhere in my PDO code...

// get the ID
    $theID = ( isset( $_GET['ID'] ) ) ? $_GET['ID'] : false;

```
$sql ="SELECT count(*) from writing
LEFT JOIN stories on writing.SID = stories.SID
LEFT JOIN wp_users ON writing.ID = wp_users.ID
WHERE (wp_users.ID != :theID) AND (writing.approved = :approved) AND (stories.ID =
```

:theID)";

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':theID', $theID, PDO::PARAM_INT); 
$stmt->bindParam(':approved', $m = Y, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Problem was I was using the same named paramter :theID more than once. I changed it to :theID1 and :theID2 and had two seperate bindParam statements for each and it worked.